# How to calculate the process control limits when there is not much data left?

Tags: moving-average, quality-control

**Context:**

To compute the "Process Control" limits, I am following the [Stacey Barr's blog](https://www.staceybarr.com/measure-up/interpreting-signals-in-trending-kpis/).

**My question:**

After detecting the signal, if I don't have enough data points left in my dataframe, for example, there are a total of 100 rows in my dataframe and signal was detected on 97th row. So clearly, I don't have enough rows (samples) left to compute the half averages (assuming we need at least 9 points as mentioned in the blog) and further the process control limits.

What should we do in such cases?